# How do I make an USB printer halt mid-print?

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, usb, halt

What I'm trying to do is make a USB printer behave a bit more like a dot matrix printer in the sense of being able to control when a page is actually ejected.

What I want to do is use two pdf files, one for the top of the page and one for the bottom, and have the printer print the first pdf, halt and wait for the second pdf to show up, then continue printing the second pdf on the second half of the page.

The idea here is that the first part of the paper should be able to be torn from a perforated page without having to wait for the second half to be done. I'm using C# and have looked at many different ways of printing raw data, but I'm not finding very much on this matter. Thank you all in advance and please let me know if any information is needed!

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible (well, it might be with a custom driver, but such is outside the scope of a basic inquiry and requires inside knowledge of a particular printer). In modern ("non-direct") printing the print information (ie. the entire page / pages to print) is sent to the print spooler. Then the spooler (and the underlying drivers it uses) process the print job - and full pages - as a single unit. This is much different than the 'standardized' LPT printing of old where the device would wait for each line to come in (via "direct" operations).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was afraid of it being a driver-level issue but I figured I would ask. Is there a way I can upvote your response?